# Python class inheriting multiprocessing, trouble with accessing class members

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In short, say I have the following:

```
import multiprocessing

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        print "Init"
        self.value = None

    def run(self):
        print "Running"
        self.value = 1

p = Worker()
p.start()
p.join()
print p.value
```

I'd expect the output to be:

```
Init
Running
1
```

Instead it is

```
Init
Running
None
```

Can someone explain to me why this is the case? What am I not understanding, and how should I go about doing it correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The moment you say `p.start()`, a separate process is forked off of the main process. All variable values are copied. So the main process has one copy of `p`, and the forked process has a separate copy of `p`. The `Worker` modifies the forked process's copy of `p.value`, but the main process's `p.value` still is `None`.

There are many ways to share objects between processes. In this case, perhaps the easiest way is to use a [mp.Value](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Worker(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Init"
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.num = mp.Value('d', 0.0)

    def run(self):
        print "Running"
        self.num.value = 1

p = Worker()
p.start()
p.join()
print p.num.value
```

Note that the `mp.Value` has a default value of `0.0`. It can not be set to `None`.

Comment: Thanks. It also seems like creating the num value within the constructor (as opposed to constructing it in main and passing it) also works fine. I'll leave the answer unaccepted for a little while (as I've heard is customary in SO).

Comment: You can use MangerPools for better type handling